# Meteor: copy document to another collection and delete from original collection after 'expirationDate'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, cron

I am looking for an efficient way to publish blog posts if the `expirationDate` (which is a field in the blog document) has not passed the the current date.

The following is a simple working solution but please read below what I am aiming to do.

```
Meteor.publish('nonExpiredBlogs', function() {
    var blogIds = []
    var currentDate = new Date()

    Blogs.find().forEach(function(doc) {
        var expirationDate = doc.expirationDate
        var hasExpDatePassed = (expirationDate - currenDate) < 0

        if (hasExpDatePassed === false) { // expiration date is Not passed, get the doc _id
            blogIds.push(doc._id)
        }
    });

    return Blog.find({_id: {$in: {_id: blogIds}}});
}
```

I am wondering if there is an alternative where I dont need a 'forEach' function that may be quicker to compute.

For example, can I implement `npm node-cron-jobs` to check if the `expirationDate` has not passed servers current date, if so, simply copy the document to an 'Archive' collection and remove it from the Blogs collection.

I could use MongoDb's [time to live](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-ttl/) for the delete operation, however, I dont know if or how the document can be copied to another collection first - This would be the ideal solution.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use the MongoDB query with `Blog.find({_id: {$in: {_id: blogIds}}, expirationDate: {$gt: new Date()} })` to get Blog posts with a future expiration date?

Comment: Does mongoDb understand how to interoperate date values ? I will try this out now and let you know if this works

Comment: Yes, this is perfect, now I can do expirationDate: {$lt: new Date()} periodically to archive docs in to another collection and delete them

Comment: yes Mongo knows how to deal with dates but also geolocation data, it is quite powerful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create query criteria which uses the [**`$gt`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/) operator to compare documents that have the `expirationDate` field greater than the current date i.e. those documents that haven't yet expired:

```
Meteor.publish('nonExpiredBlogs', function() {
    var currentDate = new Date();    
    return Blog.find({"expirationDate": {"$gt": currentDate}});
}
```

Comment: I believe Guillaume has already provided this solution if you scroll up. Thanks for your input though

Comment: Cheers, Guillaume provided the solution `Blog.find({_id: {$in: {_id: blogIds}}, expirationDate: {$gt: new Date()} })` which still requires a for loop to get the `blogId's`, the alternative that I suggested above only takes one line.

Comment: oh yes, I didn't use the for loop (using the forEach function) as its not needed